# Why removed synched photo folders still appears on my iPhone 5S

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, photos, data-synchronization

I removed the iTunes synched photo folders from my 5S and they no longer appear on my phone. However, they are still showing up as being stored when I look at the usage on my phone. I am constantly out of memory because of these photo files I can't even see on my phone anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you remove them?

Answer (score 1):

This happens from time to time. Not just photos but other files and storage. The cure is the same routine for all of the various situations like this.

1. Unpair your watch if you have one or more Apple Watch
2. Back up your phone
3. Erase all content and settings
4. Restore the backup
5. Set things up that didn’t get backed up by design - Touch ID, Apple Pay, pair watches, etc...

You can use iCloud or a passcode to get personal details (health data) and network passwords part of the backup.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203977